# Python fast array multiplication for multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, numpy-einsum

I have two 3-dimensional arrays, **A**, **B**, where

1. **A** has dimensions (500 x 500 x 80), and
2. **B** has dimensions (500 x 80 x 2000).

In both arrays the dimension that has the size 80 can be called 'time' (e.g. 80 timepoints `i`). The dimension that has the size 2000 can be called 'scenario' (we have 2000 `scenario`s).

What I need to do is to take 500 x 500 matrix `A[:, :, i]` and multiply by it each 500-element column vector at a corresponding time `B[:, i, scenario]` for each `scenario` and time `i`.

I eventually ended up with the code below

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
A = norm.rvs(size = (500, 500, 80),  random_state = 0)
B = norm.rvs(size = (500, 80, 2000), random_state = 0)
result = np.einsum('ijk,jkl->ikl', A, B, optimize=True)
```

while a naive approach would for the same problem be to use a nested for loop

```
for scenario in range(2000):
    for i in range(80):
         out[:, i, scenario] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i, scenario]
```

I expected `einsum` to be quite fast because the problem 'only' involves simple operations on a large array but it actually runs for several minutes.

I compared the speed of the `einsum` above to the case where we assume that each matrix in **A** is the same, we can keep **A** as a (500 x 500) matrix (instead of a 3d array), and then the whole problem can be written as

```
A = norm.rvs(size = (500, 500),      random_state = 0)
B = norm.rvs(size = (500, 80, 2000), random_state = 0)
result = np.einsum('ij,jkl->ikl', A, B, optimize=True)
```

This is fast and only runs for a few seconds. Much faster than the 'slightly' more general case above.

My question is - do I write the general case with the slow `einsum` in a computationally efficient form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do better than the existing two nested loops one with one loop instead -

```
m = A.shape[0]
n = B.shape[2]
r = A.shape[2]
out1 = np.empty((m,r,n), dtype=np.result_type(A.dtype, B.dtype))
for i in range(r):
    out1[:,i,:] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i,:]
```

Alternatively, with [`np.matmul/@ operator`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
out = (A.transpose(2,0,1) @ B.transpose(1,0,2)).swapaxes(0,1)
```

These two seem to scale much better than `einsum` version.

#### Timings

**Case #1 : Scaled 1/4th sizes**

```
In [44]: m = 500
    ...: n = 2000
    ...: r = 80
    ...: m,n,r = m//4, n//4, r//4
    ...: 
    ...: A = norm.rvs(size = (m, m, r),  random_state = 0)
    ...: B = norm.rvs(size = (m, r, n), random_state = 0)

In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: out1 = np.empty((m,r,n), dtype=np.result_type(A.dtype, B.dtype))
    ...: for i in range(r):
    ...:     out1[:,i,:] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i,:]
175 ms ± 6.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit (A.transpose(2,0,1) @ B.transpose(1,0,2)).swapaxes(0,1)
165 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [47]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,jkl->ikl', A, B, optimize=True)
483 ms ± 13.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

and as we scale up, the memory congestion would start favouring the one-loop version.

**Case #2 : Scaled 1/2 sizes**

```
In [48]: m = 500
    ...: n = 2000
    ...: r = 80
    ...: m,n,r = m//2, n//2, r//2
    ...: 
    ...: A = norm.rvs(size = (m, m, r),  random_state = 0)
    ...: B = norm.rvs(size = (m, r, n), random_state = 0)

In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: out1 = np.empty((m,r,n), dtype=np.result_type(A.dtype, B.dtype))
    ...: for i in range(r):
    ...:     out1[:,i,:] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i,:]
2.9 s ± 58.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [50]: %timeit (A.transpose(2,0,1) @ B.transpose(1,0,2)).swapaxes(0,1)
3.02 s ± 94.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Case #3 : Scaled 67% sizes**

```
In [59]: m = 500
    ...: n = 2000
    ...: r = 80
    ...: m,n,r = int(m/1.5), int(n/1.5), int(r/1.5)

In [60]: A = norm.rvs(size = (m, m, r),  random_state = 0)
    ...: B = norm.rvs(size = (m, r, n), random_state = 0)

In [61]: %%timeit
    ...: out1 = np.empty((m,r,n), dtype=np.result_type(A.dtype, B.dtype))
    ...: for i in range(r):
    ...:     out1[:,i,:] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i,:]
25.8 s ± 4.9 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [62]: %timeit (A.transpose(2,0,1) @ B.transpose(1,0,2)).swapaxes(0,1)
29.2 s ± 2.41 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

#### Numba spin-off

```
from numba import njit, prange
    
@njit(parallel=True)
def func1(A, B):
    m = A.shape[0]
    n = B.shape[2]
    r = A.shape[2]
    out = np.empty((m,r,n))
    for i in prange(r):
        out[:,i,:] = A[:, :, i] @ B[:, i,:]
    return out
```

Timings with case #3 -

```
In [80]: m = 500
    ...: n = 2000
    ...: r = 80
    ...: m,n,r = int(m/1.5), int(n/1.5), int(r/1.5)

In [81]: A = norm.rvs(size = (m, m, r),  random_state = 0)
    ...: B = norm.rvs(size = (m, r, n), random_state = 0)

In [82]: %timeit func1(A, B)
653 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The single for loop indeed dominates when the sizes are bigger. (Probably because it leverages the benefits of broadcasting?) I wrote the single-loop multiplication as a function decorated by `@njit` from numba. And boom! Even full size arrays multiply in 3 seconds! You really made my day!

Comment: @user2743931 Added numba version. Does this one do better than what you have?

Comment: Wow, it is not pretty crazily fast. My processor doesn't have many cores but the additional boost is still 50%. True genius!

Comment: You could change the pure Python version in the inner loop to `np.copy(A[:, :, k]) @ np.copy(B[:, k,:])`, than the pure Python version also makes use of a BLAS call (1,3s-> same as Numba with parallel=False). If you optimize all repeated memory allocations away (3 copyto's) you get the same performance as Numba with parallel=True. This is actually the same what Numba does here. I am wondering why the first optimization isn't present in pure Python when a dot product on large matrices is performed.